# javascript global variable scope

Tags: javascript, coding-style

So I hear that variable in js that initialized without a "var" will be global. so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function foo(){
         //since i'm not using "var", will this function become global?
      }

      var bar = function(){
         //is this the better way to declare the function?
      }
})
```

If it is global, why I can't access it in the console. If it's not global, and it's scope is in the function, will omitting "var" cost some performances? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only variables declared without `var` become global, this does not apply to functions.

You can, however, declare foo like so:

```
foo = function() {}
```

and it should be global.

Omitting `var` is generally not recommended for these reasons (off the top of head):

- Variable resolution starts at the most local and goes toward looking in the global namespace, making it slower. Much slower in certain browsers.
- You tend to eventually have naming conflicts by polluting the global namespace. One of the worst offenders would be, say, `for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` (note the lack of `var`)

You might want to declare functions using `var` due to a language feature called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting)

BTW, if you do choose to declare functions with `var`, I recommend you do so this way:

```
var foo = function foo() {}
```

because it gives the function a "name" instead of being treated as an anonymous function, which will help with debugging. Most people do not do this and declare using `function`, I believe.

Comment: +1 for using `... = function foo() { }`.  Didn't know you could double-name like that.